# Как в foreach цикле занести неопределенное кол-во данных в массив?

Tags: php

Есть бд, в которой есть таблица **"Achievements"** в которой есть неопределенное количество полей **"name"**.

Нужно с помощью ajax запроса получить массив, содержащий **все замечания name** в таблице.

Запрос я сделал, у меня возникает проблема в записи этого массива на стороне **PHP**

```
<?php
    require "db.php";
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) {
      // Получаем id users чья сессия
      $userid = $_SESSION['logged_user']->id;
      // Загружаем данные об этом user
      $user = R::Load('users', $userid);

      // $achievment это грубо говоря таблица в бд, где содержится поле name
      foreach( $user->ownAchievementsList as $achievment ) {
          //Как здесь занести неопределенное множество значений "name" 
          //в массив и передать его обратно в ajax запрос?
          $a1 = $achievment->name;
      }


    }
    echo json_encode(???);
    ?>
```

Comment: Что означает "неопределенное количество"? В базе данных у каждой колонки будет это поле

Comment: `$a1[] = $achievment->name;`

Comment: @ishidex2 В поле name может быть неопределенное кол-во значений

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как я решил эту проблему:

```
$a1 = [];
foreach( $user->ownAchievementsList as $achievment ) {  
    array_push ($a1, $achievment ->name);
}

echo json_encode($a1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a1 = [];
foreach( $user->ownAchievementsList as $achievment ) {
    $a1[] = $achievment->name;
}

echo json_encode($a1);
```